# Unity 3D Cloth stretch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cloth-simulation

I developed a game where the user adjusts the angle and power to launch the ball with to try to score in the goal. I designed a Plane with a large amount of vertices for the mesh and imported it to unity. The ball hits the net well although  the net not always stretches. for example if i set the angle to 17 degrees and power 100, for some reason, the cloth doesnt work. But regarding an issue im having with it is that I want to not simulate at the beginning, and should only simulate when the ball hits the cloth. The other thing: Is there anyway to make the cloth stretch even more and engulfs the ball in a way ? Thanks

Comment: Please attached the script and try to make your question more clear.

Comment: No scripts are needed. All i need is a way to make the cloth (my goal net) stretch more when the ball makes contact with it because currently it doesnt stretch much and ball is reflected back.

Comment: You probably have to change weight of the ball.

Comment: hmm i tried increasing the mass to be honest but it doesnt seem to make any difference :/